# Read list - select() - what's going there? (Python 2.6)

Tags: python, sockets, select, python-2.6, recv

I'm trying to create a connection between a server to many clients using select.
I have tried this only with one client, but after he connects (works fine), the client tries to send his username and the server tries to recieve it, but an error in the server says that the connection was forcely closed by the client. Does anybody knows why?

EDIT: I've done some changes in my code but I still have a similar problem.. here it is:

Server:

```
global players
players = {}
global players_sockets
players_sockets = []
while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([server_socket] + players_sockets, players_sockets, [], 0.3)
    print rlist
    for current_socket in rlist:
        if current_socket is server_socket:
            ((new_socket, address)) = server_socket.accept()
            players_sockets.append(new_socket) 
        else:
            msg = current_socket.recv(1024)
            if msg == '':
                players_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                del players[get_key_from_dict(players, value)]
            else:
                players[msg] = current_socket
```

(When msg == '', client quits; Else it he's username)

Client:

```
while True:
            rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([my_socket], [my_socket], [], 0.3)
                            print wlist
            if rlist:
                msg = my_socket.recv(1024)
                print msg
            if wlist:
                for message in messages_to_send:
                    my_socket.send(message)
                    print message
                    messages_to_send.remove(message)
            for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    messages_to_send.append('')
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Everything is sitting inside a while(true) loop, I bet that it will get to your else statement every time.

Comment: You probably don't want to unconditionally include all of your players_sockets in the second argument to select().  The only sockets that should be in that are any sockets that you want to do a non-blocking send() on ASAP.  If you include a socket in that list that you do not want to send to, then you are unnecessarily causing select() to return immediately whenever that socket has buffer space available to accept outgoing data -- which is to say, almost all the time. That will cause select() to return immediately most every time, which will cause your program to chew on the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Well, I don't know how to write it differently so it won't go there all the time. I have changed my code actually, but I still got a similar problem. The new code is in the edit..